# DefaultHttpClient not working to request for Webservice

Tags: android, json, web-services, httpclient, httpconnection

In one of my application there is webservice calling which is developed in PHP. And i have used the common method for requesting the webservice response which is in JSON format.The method `parseJson()` i have written is in CommonUtiliy file and this is reusable. I use the same method in all over application.

Now my problem is the `parseJson()` method for requesting the response was working perfectly few days before but now its not working at all for some webservices. I am not able to get the response for some webservice and i get the below error. I am getting null response.

Can any one guide for this? Why this is happening? As it was working before.

**Error:**

```
10-29 06:40:04.381: W/System.err(3404): JSON Response--->
10-29 06:40:04.381: W/System.err(3404): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
10-29 06:40:04.381: W/System.err(3404):     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
10-29 06:40:04.381: W/System.err(3404):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
10-29 06:40:04.381: W/System.err(3404):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
10-29 06:40:04.381: W/System.err(3404):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
10-29 06:40:04.381: W/System.err(3404):     at com.zeal.peak.adapter.GridAdapter$callLikeWS.doInBackground(GridAdapter.java:381)
10-29 06:40:04.381: W/System.err(3404):     at com.zeal.peak.adapter.GridAdapter$callLikeWS.doInBackground(GridAdapter.java:1)
10-29 06:40:04.381: W/System.err(3404):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-29 06:40:04.381: W/System.err(3404):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-29 06:40:04.381: W/System.err(3404):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-29 06:40:04.381: W/System.err(3404):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-29 06:40:04.381: W/System.err(3404):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-29 06:40:04.393: W/System.err(3404):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

**Request Method:**

```
  /*
 * Call the Webservice read the Json response and return the response in
 * string.
 */
public static String parseJSON(String p_url) {

    String json = null;
    try {
        // Create a new HTTP Client
        DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // Setup the get request
        HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet(BaseUrl + p_url);
        System.out.println("Request URL--->" + BaseUrl + p_url);
        // Execute the request in the client
        HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultClient.execute(httpGetRequest);
        // Grab the response
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        json = reader.readLine();
        System.err.println("JSON Response--->" + json);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // In your production code handle any errors and catch the
        // individual exceptions
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return json;
}
```

**EDITED:**

But if i use the same code in my java file only besides accessing it from the commonutils file then its working fine. As below:

```
         @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String m_response = null;
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(BaseUrl
                + "notification_list.php?uid=" + m_userID);
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = client.execute(httpget);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = "";
                BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(in));
                while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                m_response = sb.toString();
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    System.err.println("Response=$^^^^^^^^^^" + m_response);
```

Here i get the response successfully. Don't know why this is happening.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your URL? Is it http or https ?

Comment: @GrIsHu It mght be that the json u are trying to receive is not the complete json and hence the error. check the url in a chrome browser and if u get the complete result then theres a mistake in how the response is obtained. Print the string response otherwise

Comment: and also check if there's an encoding suddenly set in the php web service.. n change that to UTF-8 encoding if any .

Comment: Its smoothly working in browser and the json response is also proper. I have already checked and tested it. @DharaShah

Answer (score 0):

The difference lies here, between:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
json = reader.readLine();
```

and

```
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
m_response = sb.toString();
```

The first reads only the first line from response - `bf.readLine()` reads until end of stream or end of line is found (the first line break); while the second reads all the lines until the end stream - so you have a complete JSON response. You are logging the response yourself in both cases. Why didn't you had a look in Logcat?

Changing top section to:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String json = null;
while((json = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(json);
}
json = sb.toString();
```

should do the trick

Comment: may be you are right but actually i am not getting the response at all so the thing for reading the line far from that. Though the response is null already.

Comment: `actually i am not getting the response at all` you're not mentioning this in your question. How are we supposed to know that??? Anyway, check why you're not getting the answer - make a request in browser with the same URL and if it works check if you have `INTERNET` permission set in your app ...

Comment: i already checked the things in browser already. And it works fine in browser already and i also provided the internet permission already . As i already mentioned in my question that it works fine when i use the same thing in my doInBackground method.

Comment: Then what exactly is the problem? If it works in `doInBackground`, the `json` String value is a valid JSON?

Comment: The issue i do not want to repeat the same code for each webservice calling. So i have kept that in commonutils file from where i just use `parseJson` method but it does not work for all the webservices ,whereas for some webservices i get successfull response.

Comment: `but it does not work for all the webservices ,whereas for some webservices i get successfull response.` Until you post an understandable question, I doubt someone will be able to answer.